# Is there a working sample for fit_generator with use_multiprocessing=True?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, gpu

Having hard time to make Keras' `fit_generator(...,use_multiprocessing=True)` work, while `use_multiprocessing=False` has always been working.

Tried to follow the tutorial [here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) but couldn't get it running because both the model and the data file are missing.

Is there a working python code sample with `use_multiprocessing=True`, so that I could test on my machine?

Comment: does the answer give you what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of codes that are using `use_multiprocessing=True`

Looking up this on GitHub will return thousands of snippets of code using it. Check [here](https://github.com/search?q=use_multiprocessing%3DTrue&type=Code)